# How to get all results from while loop,from function

Tags: php, arrays

So i have a problem getting all of the results from my while loop within a function.When i print the results of the function its just 1 result instead of 5-10 which i need.There is the code:

```html
function  display_post_edits($post_id,$post_name){
 global $connect;
 $result = array();
 $rev = sanitize('revision');
 $post_name = '$post_id-revision-v1'; //sanitize this soon!!
 $query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT post_author,post_date FROM posts WHERE post_type ='$rev' AND post_name = '$post_id-revision-v1'");
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
  $result[]= $row;
 }
  return $result;
}
//outside of function
$display_edits = display_post_edits(get_post_id($_POST['subject']),$_POST['subject']);
print_r($display_edits);
```

So i am trying to get all of the results from the while loop and attach it to $display_edits and when i need for example post date only i will use $display_edits['post_date'].

There are some of my tries so far:
`foreach($result as $row){
        return implode($result[0]);
    }`

Returns 1 results because $return is printing arrays like http://prntscr.com/gby0xu (array in array) so i need to define a index.Same thing with implode i need to define index.

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $result = array(
    'post_author' =>$row'post_author',
    'post_date'   =>$row'post_date'
     );
  }
```

Prints only 1 results again...
If you need anything more,or i missed something to give here please say what and i  will add it ! 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you planning to join `post_author` and `post_author`? If yes, you can do the same in `while()` loop that returning an array and processing it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `foreach` should be like this:

```
foreach($result as $row){
    return implode($row[0]);
}
```

It should use `$row` and not `$result`

Comment: Still returns 1 result only ;/

Comment: It will `return` for every record, which you can merge/join.

Comment: yaap,my bad it works i used only $row and it is returning all info in string http://prntscr.com/gbyled Thank you